# Properly close EntityManager in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a REST API with Spring managed EntityManager.
When I try to close it with

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em.

em.close();
```

I receive *IllegalStateException* which is normal because the Spring doc. says so.

**My question is:** which is the correct way to terminate a REST application created with Spring Boot? Should I be 'disturbed' by this exception?

I googled it a lot but didn't find clear information.

**EDIT:**
what is disturbing is the fact, that if I shut down my application (e.g. in Tomcat) I receive the same *IllegalStateException*.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to close the `EntityManager` connection. It will be managed by Spring. So you need to remove the line:

```
em.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! But why is it throw an Exception, when I shut down the application?

Comment: @SiGe,  which is the exception?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to specify this. I receive IllegalStateException if I close it with .close(), but also if I shut down my application. And this is what disturbing me.